# Removing items from list in form in ASP.NET MVC without using JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement a form with a list of parameters which can be added and removed by the user. The catch is that I want to do this **without javascipt**. This is to be done in ASP.NET MVC 3.

I have a form like this (simplified code, so might not be quite right, it is just to illustrate what I have got):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("New", "Films", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "NewFilmForm" }))
    {
        @if (Model.Any())
        {
        <!-- List of directors that have already been added -->
        <div id="AddedDirectors">
            @foreach (var director in Model)
            {
            <span>
                @Html.Hidden("AddedDirectors", @director)
                @Html.Raw(director)
                <!-- JQuery button to remove director -->
                <button class="deleteButton" type="button">x</button>
            </span>
            }
        </div>
        }

        <!-- Interface for adding a new director -->
        <div id="AddDirectorInterface">
            <!-- Jquery show/hide add single director interface -->
            <button type="button" id="AddDirectorButton">+ &nbsp Add a director</button>

            <div>
                @Html.TextBox("AddDirector")

                <!-- Post add button -->
                <button name="SubmitButton" value="@Html.Encode(NewFilmActions.AddDirector)">Add</button>
            </div>            
        </div>

    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="@Html.Encode(NewFilmActions.Save)">Save film</button>
}
```

I have two submit buttons here. Which are handled via a switch statement in the controller and identified via the value attribute which is set based on the NewFilmActions Enum.

Pressing the button with the AddDirector value posts to the controller, adds the name entered in the AddDirector textbox to the model and returns the view with the form again, adding the name specified by the user to the list of directors which have already been added (see commented section).

I would like to add a button allowing me to delete names which have already been added by the user...
I could put in one single button to delete all of them in one go very easily, but if posible I would like to add individual buttons. I can't figure out how to do it though.

One solution I can think off would be to append the name to the value and then in the switch statement have a default and check if the value contains a specified enum value, but that sounds a little like a botched together approach.

Can anybody either tell me how to do this or point me to some tutorial/explanations on how to implement this?

Just to emphasize: I know this can easily be done using JS, but I am looking at doing this entirely serverside for basic functionality and for my personal education.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reduce the scope of your form so it doesn't include the list.

Then you can put delete forms within you for loop, as shown below;

```
@foreach (var director in Model)
{
    <span>
        @Html.Raw(director)
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Films", FormMethod.Post, new { id = director.Id })){ <button name "DeleteButton" value="Delete">Delete</button>}
    </span>
}
```

An example of this is also shown in this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/12/asp-net-mvc-handling-multiple-form-actions-on-one-view.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that would be a good idea normally, but I don't see how I can do that and ensure that the contents of the list will be posted to the form when I press the main submit button. I mean, all the relevant fields have to be within the main form, right? So I can't take the list out of the form I think.

Comment: I guess it's not clear from your code sample what the 'director' is.  I assumed you were just displaying a list of director names.  These names are already persisted somewhere, so when you add or remove from the list you can only do one at a time, therefore why do you need to pass the whole list back as well?  I guess if you are including other inputs in your form (that you're not showing) then that would be problematic

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have posted the whole form... I am asking for input for a new film, which can have several directors and actors (not shown here), as well as title, synopsis etc... all in this form. I want to make a list to add or remove the directors and actors which have been added one by one. The difficult part is that this entry is not yet in the db and the directors and actors are not necessarily entries which have already been registered in the db. Do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: Ok then, perhaps rather than displaying all the fields including the list of directors in one form, you could split it out over a couple of  pages with a wizard like experience.  Therefore the film will exist when you get to the directors list.  Other than that I think you'll have no other choice but to use javascript - which is what I'd do :)

Comment: I see. I already have all my layout the way I want it now, so I'll stick with one page and a single "remove all" button for now (lazy, I know...). Thank you very much for the insight!